# HTML5 Canvas - image not working/showing up in ie10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, internet-explorer-10

I have just started looking into html5 and the canvas element and have been trying to create a simple page that rotates an image clockwise and anti clockwise on button clicks. I managed to get something working but i tested it on ie10 and the image is not showing up, just the blank grey canvas. I can only test on ie10 so not sure if this effects other versions too. My full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Canvas Element -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;">
</canvas> 

<!-- Rotate Buttons -->
<h2>Rotate</h2>
<button onclick="rotate('c')">Clockwise</button>
<button onclick="rotate('a')">Anti-Clockwise</button>
<button onclick="rotate('r')">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const FPS = 30;
    var imagePosX = 90;
    var imagePosY = 143;
    var imageRot = 0;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "sample.jpg";

    var canvas = null;
    var context2D = null;

    window.onload = startup;

    function startup(){
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context2D = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(draw, 500 / FPS);
    }

    function rotate(d){
        setInterval(draw(d), 500 / FPS);
    }

    function draw(d){
     if (d=='a'){imageRot -= 10;}
     if (d=='c'){imageRot += 10;}
     if (d=='r'){imageRot = 0;}
     context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context2D.save();
     context2D.translate(imagePosX+(image.width/2), imagePosY+(image.height/2));
     context2D.rotate(imageRot * Math.PI / 180);
     // optional shadow
     context2D.shadowBlur = 15;  
     context2D.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
     //
     context2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, -(image.width/2), -(image.height/2), image.width, image.height);
     context2D.restore();
    }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of how it should look (and looks in chrome/safari/firefox etc):

[image: other browsers]

Screenshot for ie10:

[image: ie10]

Can anyone help with what is causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE 10 doesn't support `const`. Change it to `var`. That at least will be one reason for it not working.

Also, the debugger (which is not that amazing in IE10) is still your friend. We'll call him 'semi-friend'. Use him. What does he say?

Comment: Thanks Jarrod, that change from `const` to `var` did the trick plus the image.onload from @Ken :)